# Center div on the middle of screen

Tags: css, semantic-ui

What is the best pattern to align a semantic ui grid in the middle of the screen?

the css for this will ideal be this one.

```
.div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

But on semantic this dont look well with grids.

This is part of my html.

```
 <div class="ui grid container">
    <div class="ui center aligned three column grid">
      <div class="column">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want both the columns horizontally and vertically centered?

Comment: Used .div instead of div in css

Answer (score 214):

This should work with any `div` or screen size:

```css
.center-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="center-screen">
 I'm in the center
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

See more details about `flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This should work on most of the browsers, see compatibility matrix [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**Update**: If you don't want the scroll bar, make `min-height` smaller, for example `min-height: 95vh;`

Comment: This is the best solution, but a friendly reminder: this does not work in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Caner Is there a way to avoid the scrollbar which will always appear?

Comment: @Esko you can make `min-height` smaller, for example `min-height: 95vh;`

Comment: @Esko I've solved this with calc(100vh - 1rem) since 1rem is supposed to be the text height

Comment: Worked  but removed min-height attribute (Not necessary)

Answer (score 100):

**2018: CSS3**

```
div {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-right: -50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

This is even shorter. For more information see this: [CSS: Centering Things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

Comment: This works for me in that it centers the div, but some of the elements in the div are now blurred.

Comment: Not even 2018. CSS3 has been around long enough that it works on all _current_ browsers. One suggestion: `position: fixed` centers it on the screen, as requested. One question: what is the significance of `margin-right: -50%` ? In my testing it seemed to work just as well without. Thanks for a good answer.

Comment: this centers in the middle of the page not in the middle of the screen. If the page is longer than the screen height this will cause a problem

Comment: @Manngo "The 'margin-right: -50%' is needed to compensate the 'left: 50%'. The 'left' rule reduces the available width for the element by 50%. The renderer will thus try to make lines that are no longer than half the width of the container. By saying that the right margin of the element is further to the right by that same amount, the maximum line length is again the same as the container's width.[...]"When you remove the 'margin-right: -50%' and resize the window, you'll see that the sentences will be broken already when the window is still twice as wide as the text lines."src: see link above

Answer (score 37):

The best way to align a div in center both horizontally and vertically will be

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ham41w60/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Here div is html tag. You wrote a html tag followed by a dot that is wrong.Only a class is written followed by dot.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct you just used `.div` instead of `div`

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui grid container">
<div class="ui center aligned three column grid">
  <div class="column">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -50px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Check out this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5t1Luat/)**